# CSS automatically adding padding and margin to unordered lists

Tags: css, padding

My all  unordered lists are having automatic padding-left of 40px and a margin top and bottom both of 12px. I checked the whole css stylesheet and unable to find any padding to the unordered list  nor to the ordered list

Please Help me I've been trying to solve this problem from hours...!

Comment: I am using Eric Meyers Css Reset. How can I send the code. Its huge.

Comment: OK I found actually it all happened due to the buggy behavior of stylizer software for css. It auto added all the tags to comment section making an invalid RULE in the css reset file from Eric Meyer. I deleted that and now its working fine. Stylizer is HELL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the browser's setting. That's why you should be using reset CSS to minimize differences between browsers. Look for this code: http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ It'll remove all default padding and margins.

To just remove it from lists:

```
ul, li
{
padding:0px; margin 0px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your great help. Actually it all happened due to the buggy behavior of stylizer software for css. It auto added all the tags to comment section making an invalid RULE in the css reset file from Eric Meyer. I deleted that and now its working fine. Stylizer is HELL.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to post some example code - we can't tell what you've done. I'm going to guess, though, that you don't have a browser reset in place.

Basically, each browser will apply default styles to elements on a page. These assumed defaults can vary from browser to browser.

Browser resets are a great idea because they remove a bunch of the default styles that a browser will apply so you start on equal footing across all browsers. I'm a fan of [the Eric Meyer reset](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/), though there are others out there.

Comment: Thanks for your great help. Actually it all happened due to the buggy behavior of stylizer software for css. It auto added all the tags to comment section making an invalid RULE in the css reset file from Eric Meyer. I deleted that and now its working fine. Stylizer is HELL.

Answer (score 0):

These most likely come from the default styles of the browser.

Simply overrule them in your own style sheet to your liking

```
ul {
  padding: 0; <<< put your values
}
```